'The' Halting Problem or Many Halting Problems?
Let us assume that we are using ZFC as our metalogic.
We have the following definitions:
Alg == Nat // The set of all algorithms (maybe turing machine descriptions)
Execute(alg: Alg, arg: Nat) : Nat ∪ {'null'} // A partial function which 'runs' the algorithm, returning 'null' if it diverges.
Pair(n1: Nat, n2: Nat) : Nat == 2^n1*3^n2 // A way to encode a pair of natural numbers as one natural number

We can define whether an algorithm solves the halting problem as follows:
SolvesHalting(a: Alg) == ∀b: Alg, ∀arg: Nat, 
                             Execute(a,Pair(b,arg)) = 1 ⇔ Execute(b,arg) = 'null' ∧
                             Execute(a,Pair(b,arg)) = 0 ⇔ Execute(b,arg) ≠ 'null' 

We have a theorem which says that the halting problem is unsolvable.
THEOREM HaltingImpossible == ∀ a: Alg, ¬ SolvesHalting(a)

The proof of HaltingImpossible is well-known and uses the diagonalization argument. (Side note: It is a negated statement, the proof is trivially constructive, I think)
The question that I have is when one 'proves' things like Godel Incompleteness of a formal system F (which is 'sufficiently powerful'), using the Halting Argument. An informal argument often goes as follows:

Assume that for all sentences φ in F, we have a proof of φ or ¬φ.
Consider Halts(tm: Alg) : FSentence, which is a sentence of F that states that tm halts on a blank tape. (Here, I'm thinking of Halts() as a metalevel operator / syntactic sugar)
Consider the following 'algorithm' halt_solver : Alg -> Nat, which enumerates proofs in F until it finds a proof of Halts(tm) or ¬Halts(tm), returning 0 and 1 respectively.
We have 'solved the halting problem'.

While it makes intuitive sense, and also seems to be constructive (we explicitly construct a halt_solver), I would like to make it formal. That is, we'd want something like EveryFStatementHasProof ⇒ ∃ a: Alg, SolvesHalting(a).
The question I have is in step 3. halt_solver is a metalogical function that solves the halting problem, which doesn't really give us an a : Alg such that SolvesHalting(a)? For instance, we our F sentences are strings, whereas all our algorithms ∈ Alg only operate on Nat.

So where is the gap in my understanding?
One idea that I had was Alg is a 'different programming language'.
Maybe we now want to have another programming language NewPl which can talk about sentences in F, etc. That is, the 'Domain' of values now includes 'built-in' strings, lists, pairs, etc., which are sufficient to talk about F
We now have a new Halting Problem for NewPl - SolvesNewPlHalting.
Finally, we can actually have something like EveryFStatementHasProof ⇒ ∃ program: NewPl, SolvesNewPlHalting(program).

Does this even make sense?
Do these results change if we use some other metalogic? Some constructive variant perhaps?

halt_solver can in principle be written down explicitly (but it would be pretty tedious to do so). The difference between strings and natural numbers is not that important and is dealt with using some Godel encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering). The important thing is that $F$ is computable which is basically exactly the condition necessary for halt_solver to actually exist.

@QiaochuYuan, thanks for responding. I think my main question is whether we can prove whether halt_solver can in principle be written down explicitly? I think that the idea is to be formal enough for a ZFC based theorem prover

@QiaochuYuan You say that we need to assume F is computable, which we probably can't say with Alg, and would need NewPl? In Alg, we could probably only things about "F 'encoded' as a Nat"?

There is a straightforward bijection between strings and natural numbers, so any algorithm on natural numbers can also be regarded as an algorithm on strings.
Or, to put it another way, while you can consider sentences in $F$ to be strings, they can also be converted to natural numbers by applying the natural bijection/encoding.  Because the correspondence is straightforward and uninteresting but tedious, we often make no distinction between a string and its encoding as a natural number, or between an algorithm operating on strings and an algorithm operating on natural numbers (which are interpreted as encodings of strings).
Consequently, you can fix up your concern by converting between strings and natural numbers as needed to make all the types match up.
At one point this was a non-trivial insight that required careful proof.  But now if you are a computer scientist, we are so used to it that it is treated as nearly obvious.  Every email you write is just a string, and it can be converted to a number by (approximately) expressing the string as a sequence of bits, and then treating that as the binary representation of a natural number -- and vice versa.  Computer scientists are used to the fact that everything can be considered a sequence of bits, including strings, numbers, or indeed algorithms (since their source code is just a string).
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering.

Perhaps you are asking whether "the halting problem for model of computation $C_1$" is different from "the halting problem for model of computation $C_2$".  (For instance, $C_1,C_2$ might be two different programming languages.)  Yes, they are formally distinct.  But it's unimportant.  The same proof of undecidability applies to all reasonable models of computation; it carries through with only minor adjustments.  As long as the model of computation has basic capabilities, you can implement each of the steps in the undecidability proof in the language, and then the same structure of proof carries through.  In practice, most models of computation / most programming languages are equivalent: given a program in $C_1$, you can translate/compile it to a program in $C_2$ in a straightforward way, and vice versa; or you can write a universal simulator in $C_1$ that interprets/runs programs in $C_2$, and vice versa.  So while the halting problem for $C_1$ is formally distinct from the halting problem for $C_2$, for most models of computation / programming languages there is a simple proof that they are "equivalent", in the sense that undecidability for either implies undecidability for the other, via a straightforward proof.  For this reason, computer scientists often don't bother distinguishing between these different instances of the halting problem, as they are all basically isomorphic.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness.

Thanks for your comment. My question is really about not reasoning about these 'natural' bijections, which I know about. The idea is to convince a 'stupid' theorem prover that they are obvious.

@SuraajKS, You asked where is the gap in your understanding, and that is what I was answering.  If you understood that and wanted to know how to encode it in a theorem prover, it would have helped if the question had stated that.  It seems straightforward to implement these encodings in a theorem prover, so at this point I'm not sure what the problem is.

@SuraajKS, I have revised my answer to try to address another aspect that might be unclear.  See the last paragraph of the revised answer to see whether that answers your questions.

Thanks a lot for your response. I'm still a little bit curious about the 'simple' proofs that programming C1 and C2 are equivalent. (For instance, I'm worried that the equivalence bijection might not be computable?). I asked another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4951604/what-is-an-effective-encoding, which seems to give an answer..
